# TableView DidSelectRowAt will change background colors of other cells when I scroll

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, tableview

I have a TableView sometimes with enough cells allowing me to scroll through the table. At the same time I have set my didSelectRow to switch the background color of the cell. It seems that after selecting a few then scrolling down I find that more cells have been selected out of my control.

Here is my didSelectRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   packSizesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
   packList[indexPath.row].picked = true
   pickedRows.append(indexPath)
```

Is there another way I should be selecting my table cells other than changing the color if the indexPath.row?

Comment: you should override `setSelected(_:animated:)` in the `UITableView` cell and set the color there.

Comment: Are you wanting every cell to change colour when selected and then stay that colour from then on?  It would also be worth explaining how you are registering/creating/reusing your tableView cells as the random colouring sounds like an issue in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set cell color in cellForRowAt method as below:-

```
If packList[indexPath.row].picked {
    yourCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow 
}  else {
    yourCell.backgroundColor =  UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but could use some explanation. Because the cells are queued and recycled, as you scroll up and down the same cell where you set a background color will be re-used in a different position. You need to reset such conditions in cellForRowAt every time you allocate a cell to avoid the problem. To do so, you should set the color for either condition, as @Nexus does here.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You are seeing the colors change on the wrong cells because cells get reused, and you need to set the color to the correct option when a cell is reused.

In the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method you can check your `packList` array to see if the cell being dequeued needs to be selected or not and set the color there.  This will handle cases where a new cell is being created *as well as* cells that are being reused.

```
if packList[indexPath.row].picked {
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.selectedColor
} else {
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.defaultColor
}
```

You have several options for handling selecting/deselecting, so here is one option.  In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` you can simply do:

```
packList[indexPath.row].picked = !packList[indexPath.row].picked
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.whateverYouWant)
```

You could also do just update your packList array (which is needed for cellForRow), and override the logic in your cell's `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` method.